# Windows 10 Automatic Update tries to install manually installed update - How to turn it off?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Some time ago I got repeatedly the message that an update failed to install (KB4493464). So I went to the Windows Update Download Center and downloaded the very same cumulative update manually. I went on to install the update manually, as per the messages: Successfully! Windows Update continues to try to install that update, failing at it. Yes I already deleted the SoftwareDistribution folder in my Windows Installation directory.

How do I tell Windows to stop trying to install that update?

Comment: Have you tried to perform a Windows Update reset?  You should also reboot  the machine.

Comment: The machine was rebooted several times as this whole dilemma happens for weeks now. The machine was naturally shut down several times by now. A Windows Update Reset?

Comment: [Windows Update Reset](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24742-reset-windows-update-windows-10-a.html)